# Django: Can I check if a model instance matches a filter without filtering all model instances

Tags: python, django, django-models, filter, django-queryset

I have an instance of a model. I have a queryset. Can I check if the instance matches a filter without filtering all model objects?

Situation:
I have a model `Alpha`, when this model is created I need to check if it matches a user defined filter which is stored in model `Bravo`. There will be many `Alpha` models and many `Bravo` models (filters).

```
class Alpha(models.Model):
    test = models.CharField()

class Bravo(models.Model):
    test = models.CharField()

    def get_qs(self):
        # These could be longish and complex, defined by users
        return Q(test=self.test) | Q(test=f"{self.test}a")

# There will be many of these but I only want to check this instance
a = Alpha(test="testa")
# There will be many of these, I need to check if queries from get_qs match "a"
b = Bravo(test="test")

# Lots of Bravo, all need to be checked, unavoidable
for bravo in Bravo.objects.all():
    # Lots of Alpha, don't want to check them all
    # Just check "a" matches bravo.get_qs filter
    if a in Alpha.objects.filter(bravo.get_qs()):
        # Do something with "a" depending on which "b"
        pass
```

My assumption is

```
if a in Alpha.objects.filter(bravo.get_qs())
```

Will filter all `Alpha` objects. I don't want this because I don't need to check any other instances apart from "a" and there will be a lot. I don't want to check all `Alpha` objects for each `Bravo` object.

I am open to other suggestions on how I might go about doing something similar to the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `a in Alpha.objects.filter(bravo.get_qs())`, you can check that a queryset having same primary key as `a` [exists](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists) in `Alpha`.

```py
alpha = Alpha.objects.filter(pk=a.pk)

for bravo in Bravo.objects.all():
    if alpha.filter(bravo.get_qs()).exists():
        # Do something with "a" depending on which "b"
```

Comment: If I use the `pk` I won't know which `Bravo` matches. I could do `Alpha.objects.filter(bravo.get_qs()).exists()`, I'm not sure what the difference is between `exists` and `in` and if it would be an improvement.

Comment: you can chain filters. `exists` is an improvement over `in` because in addition it's filtering by a primary key. Ideally the returned QuerySet from the first filter operation should match a single record and return an Alpha instance